# FadeIn li after li jquery wont work

Tags: jquery, fadein, portfolio

I'm making a portfolio grid with a fadeIn effect that fades in li after li (portfolio image after the next one).

I've tried many approaches but it won't work.

```
(function($){
  $.fn.showdelay = function(){
    var delay = 0;
    return this.each(function(){
      $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(1800);
      delay += 1000;
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#portfolioslider li').showdelay();
});
```

How can I fix this?

Many thanks in advance.

[Here](http://tinyurl.com/nn95bd4) is the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `display:none` to your `#porfolioslider li` style:

```
#portfolioslider li {
    float: left;
    display:none;
}
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rC7Lr/3/

Remember that in order to `fadeIn` something, it must be hidden first. If it is already visible, what are you going to fade in? :)

Comment: Thanks for your explaination! I fogot that one about hiding first before fadIn. It works now!